# Should Android Action Bar looks like iOS navigation bar

Tags: android, ios, user-interface, user-experience

We have an App for both iOS and Android platforms. Currently our designers have designed similar User Interface for two of them, just have minor differences. Since those two shared lots of common features like buttons, text fields, etc, having similar interface works for both platforms. However, the most obviously differences between iOS and Android (from my point of view), are UINavigationBar in iOS and ActionBar in Android.

Now our interface for Action Bar and Navigation Bar looks like this:[image]

[image]

This is followed UINavigation Design that have Title in centre. I'm just wondering should I keep the title centre in Android's Action Bar so two platforms will have similar interface or should I follow Android's design guide (Title next to left icon) for better Android User Experience?

Comment: BTW, you might want to be careful posting those images.  Your company might consider that to be confidential/internal information.

Comment: @EJK Thanks, but don't worry, I'm the boss. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [Pure Android](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/pure-android.html):

> Most developers want to distribute their apps on multiple platforms. As you plan your app for Android, keep in mind that different platforms play by different rules and conventions. Design decisions that make perfect sense on one platform will look and feel misplaced in the context of a different platform. While a "design once, ship anywhere" approach might save you time up-front, you run the very real risk of creating inconsistent apps that alienate users.

This advice definitely applies to the app bar, which has [very clear design guidelines](http://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/structure.html#structure-app-bar) as part of the [Material Design guide](http://www.google.com/design/spec/material-design/introduction.html), which is the driving force behind Android design at this time and is supported across all API 7+ devices via [AppCompat](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html).

Comment: This make sense, and follow android default design pattern can reduce work for coding.

Comment: You'll find all of the tooling and libraries such as AppCompat assume you are following the design guidelines: fighting them to build a design that is going to feel odd when compared to other apps on the user's Android device doesn't seem like a worthwhile use of time.

Answer (score 0):

See: https://developer.android.com/design/index.html.

This is somewhat opinion-based, but it is probably best to adhere to the Android styles where applicable, rather than shoot for consistency between you iOS and Android versions.  If you want your users to have a comfortable, familiar experience, then keep in mind that they are probably most familiar with other apps on that specific device type.

An argument for consistency between Android and iOS would be (a) simpler to design for, (b) might be easier to test, (c) easier to support.

This all assumes you are building native apps.  If you are making an HTML or hybrid app, a more device-neutral style might be acceptable.